# Problema gtk+python , desplazar un botón

Tags: python, gtk

Buenas estoy haciendo un código para desplazar un botón mediante ratón , tengo creada tanto la event box para detectar movimientos así como la fixed para desplazarla , pero no se produce movimiento , alguien ve algún fallo?

```
import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')
import gtk

class ejemplo():
    def drag_start(self,widget,event):
        self.arrastrando = True
        self.posx = int(event.x_root)
        self.posy = int(event.y_root)
        return gtk.TRUE

    def drag_end(self,widget,event):
        self.arrastrando = False
        self.xa = int(event.x_root) - self.posx
        self.ya = int(event.y_root) - self.posy
        self.xfin = self.posx + self.xa
        self.yfin =  self.posy + self.ya
        self.fixed.move(widget,self.xfin,self.yfin )

    def drag(self,widget,event):
        if not self.arrastrando:
            return gtk.FALSE
        self.xa = int(event.x_root) - self.posx
        self.ya = int(event.y_root) - self.posy
        self.xfin = self.posx + self.xa
       self.yfin =  self.posy + self.ya
        self.fixed.move(widget,self.xfin,self.yfin )
        return gtk.TRUE

    def __init__(self):
        self.window = gtk.Window()
        self.window.set_title("Event Box")
       self.window.connect("destroy", lambda w: gtk.main_quit())
        self.window.set_default_size (420,490)
        self.caja = gtk.EventBox()
        self.caja.show()
        self.fixed = gtk.Fixed()
        self.fixed.show()
        self.button = gtk.Button()
        self.button.set_size_request(70,70)
        self.button.show()


        self.posx = 0
        self.posy = 0
        self.arrastrando = None

        self.caja.set_events(gtk.gdk.BUTTON_PRESS_MASK |         
        gtk.gdk.BUTTON_RELEASE_MASK | gtk.gdk.POINTER_MOTION_MASK)
        self.caja.connect("button-press-event",self.drag_start)
        self.caja.connect("button-release-event",self.drag_end)
        self.caja.connect("motion-notify-event",self.drag)

        self.window.add(self.fixed)
        self.fixed.put(self.caja,50,50)
        self.caja.add(self.button)

        self.window.show_all()


def main():
    gtk.main()
    return 0
if __name__ == "__main__":
   ejemplo()
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado :

```
import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')
import gtk

class ejemplo():
    def drag_start(self,widget,event):
       self.arrastrando = True
       self.posx = int(event.x_root)
       self.posy = int(event.y_root)
       return gtk.TRUE

   def drag_end(self,widget,event):
       self.arrastrando = False
       self.xa = int(event.x_root) - self.posx
       self.ya = int(event.y_root) - self.posy

   def drag(self,widget,event):
       if not self.arrastrando:
           return gtk.FALSE
       self.xa = int(event.x_root) - self.posx
       self.ya = int(event.y_root) - self.posy
       self.xfin = self.posx + self.xa
       self.yfin =  self.posy + self.ya
       self.fixed.move(widget,self.xfin,self.yfin )
       return gtk.TRUE

   def __init__(self):
       self.window = gtk.Window()
       self.window.set_title("Event Box")
       self.window.connect("destroy", lambda w: gtk.main_quit())
       self.window.set_default_size (400,400)
       self.caja = gtk.EventBox()
       self.caja.show()
       self.fixed = gtk.Fixed()
       self.fixed.show()
       self.img = gtk.Image() 
       self.img.set_from_file("car4.png")
       self.img.set_size_request(60,60) 
       self.img.show()


       self.posx = 0
       self.posy = 0
       self.arrastrando = None

       self.caja.set_events(gtk.gdk.BUTTON_PRESS_MASK | 
       gtk.gdk.BUTTON_RELEASE_MASK | gtk.gdk.POINTER_MOTION_MASK)
       self.caja.connect("button-press-event",self.drag_start)

       self.caja.connect("button-release-event",self.drag_end)
       self.caja.connect("motion-notify-event",self.drag)

       self.window.add(self.fixed)
       self.fixed.put(self.caja,0,0)
       self.caja.add(self.img)
       self.caja.modify_bg(gtk.STATE_NORMAL,       
       self.caja.get_colormap().alloc_color("green")) 

       self.window.show_all()


def main():
    gtk.main()
    return 0
 if __name__ == "__main__":
    ejemplo()
    main()
```